# Matching Urls Inside Strings

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to write a regex that will match urls inside strings of text that may be html-encoded. I am having a considerable amount of trouble with lookaround though. I need something that would correctly match both links in the string below:

```
 some text "http://www.notarealwebsite.com/?q=asdf&searchOrder=1" &quot;http://www.notarealwebsite.com&quot; some other text
```

A verbose description of what I want would be: "http://" followed by any number of characters that are not spaces, quotes, or the string "&quot[semicolon]" (I don't care about accepting other non-url-safe characters as delimiters)

I have tried a few regexes using lookahead to check for &'s followed by q's followed by u's and so on, but as soon as I put one into the [^...] negation it just completely breaks down and evaluates more like: "http:// followed by any number of characters that are not spaces, quotes, ampersands, q's, u's, o's, t's, or semicolons" which is obviously not what I am looking for.

This will correctly match the &'s at the beginning of the &quot[semicolon]:

```
&(?=q(?=u(?=o(?=t(?=;)))))
```

But this does not work:

```
http://[^ "&(?=q(?=u(?=o(?=t(?=;)))))]*
```

I know just enough about regexes to get into trouble, and that includes not knowing why this won't work the way I want it to. I understand to some extent positive and negative lookaround, but I don't understand why it breaks down inside the [^...]. Is it possible to do this with regexes? Or am I wasting my time trying to make it work?

Comment: Everything inside the square brackets only matches a single character, e.g. [a-zA-z] matches _one_ character of that group. You can negate a group with ^, right. That will match any character not described by that group. But you can't negate anything else, such as a whole expression.

Comment: &(?=q(?=u(?=o(?=t(?=;))))) matches only a single character though, so I would expect it to work even with the understanding that the square brackets only do one character. Will expressions inside square brackets not even be evaluated? Like, literally it just looks at each character individually and doesn't even notice that they form an expression?

Comment: Right, the brackets can actually only contain an enumeration of characters, ^ and - are just syntactic sugar so you don't have to write [abcdef...] for [a-z]. So your expression is not evaluated, instead it just matches anything that's not one of the chars mentioned after the ^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your regex implementation supports it, use a positive look ahead and a backreference with a non-greedy expression in the body.

Here is one with your conditions: `(["\s]|&quot;)(http://.*?)(?=\1)`

For example, in Python:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(["\s]|&quot;)(https?://.*?)(?=\1)', re.IGNORECASE)
url = "http://test.url/here.php?var1=val&var2=val2"
formatstr = 'text "{0}" more text {0} and more &quot;{0}&quot; test greed&quot;'
data = formatstr.format(url)    
for m in p.finditer(data):
    print "Found:", m.group(2)
```

Produces:

```
Found: http://test.url/here.php?var1=val&var2=val2
Found: http://test.url/here.php?var1=val&var2=val2
Found: http://test.url/here.php?var1=val&var2=val2
```

Or in Java:

```
@Test
public void testRegex() {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\"\\s]|&quot;)(https?://.*?)(?=\\1)", 
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    final String URL = "http://test.url/here.php?var1=val&var2=val2";
    final String INPUT = "some text " + URL + " more text + \"" + URL + 
            "\" more then &quot;" + URL + "&quot; testing greed &quot;";

    Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT);
    while( m.find() ) {
        System.out.println("Found: " + m.group(2));
    }
}
```

Produces the same output.

Comment: This is actually a great idea and something that I did manage to adapt to a completely different use in my application just now. That being said, I can't seem to get it to work for my original question. When I run it in my Java application, the matched strings correctly omit any following delimiters, but they also incorrectly contain any leading ones. I also could not get it to work quite right when adding a space as delimiter.

Comment: I updated the example with a Java version and added your space-enclosed case.  If you use match group 2 it will give the correct result (without the leading delimiter).  Please accept the answer if this is working for you.

Comment: Thanks Jake! Bonus points for reminding me that I need to handle https also.